# React Native Slider should receive swipe and touch gestures, but these are sent to parent ScrollView on Android

Tags: react-native, slider, scrollview, gesture, react-native-flatlist

In my app, I have horizontal `FlatList` which is used for swiping between several sub-pages of a screen. This works great.

However, on one of the pages, I have a `Slider` component. On iOS it works fine, but on Android, the parent `ScrollView` of the `FlatList` seems to "steal" the swipe gesture. I am only able to adjust the `Slider` by clicking very precisely on its thin line, but I cannot adjust it by sliding.

What I need is something like one of these

- A view that wraps the `Slider` component and stops swipe gestures from being propagated to the parent `ScrollView`
- A way to make the `FlatList`/`ScrollView` not consume swipes directly on elements that responds to horizontal swipes themself
- Somehow adjust the area of which the Slider component will eat the touches around it (it's very small and hard to hit directly). I already tried adding a `hitSlop` prop, with no luck.

Any suggestions for a solution are very appreciated :)

Check example code and result here.

https://snack.expo.io/@esbenvb/mad-yogurt

[image]

Comment: i am facing same issue any solution ?